# JavaScript objects and getter properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't figure this out. How come I get `NaN` and `null` for `volume1` and `volume2` properties?

```js
undefined = ''[0];

function Set(defaults) {
    $.extend(this, {
     repCount: undefined,
        weight: undefined,
     get volume1() {
      return this.repCount * this.weight;
     }
    });
    
    if (defaults) {
     $.extend(this, defaults);
    }
}

$.extend(Set.prototype, {
    get volume2() {
     return this.repCount * this.weight;
    }
});

var firstSet = new Set({
    weight: 135,
    repCount: 8
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(firstSet));
document.write("<br />");
document.write(firstSet.volume2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It appears as though you may be trying to extend a built-in object (`Set`), which may not be possible in the implementation you are using...

Comment: Try logging `this` inside the getter, and you'd be suprised to see that it's not the `Set` object at all, meaning `this.repCount` etc. is undefined

Answer (score 2):

Did some debugging and I saw that your getter method was using the instance of "undefined" to multiple the two in your constructor. So undefined * undefined would return NaN. I changed the way the script constructs Set objects to get it to work, it's now returning a number as properties of the object set in the constructor and don't have a default of undefined.

You can see that it's doing what I'm describing by setting your document.write to get volume1, changing your getter to return this.repCount, and setting repCount to 0, or undefined, as i've done here:

```
undefined = ''[0];

        function Set(defaults) {
            $.extend(this, {
                repCount: 0,
                weight: 0,
                get volume1() {
                    return this.repCount;
                }
            });

            if (defaults) {
                $.extend(this, defaults);
            }
        }

        $.extend(Set.prototype, {
            get volume2() {
                return this.repCount;
            }
        });

        var firstSet = new Set({
            weight: 135,
            repCount: 8
        });

        document.write(JSON.stringify(firstSet));
        document.write("<br />");
        document.write(firstSet.volume2);
```

Here's the working code:

```
        undefined = ''[0];

        function Set(weight, repCount) {
            this.weight = weight;
            this.repCount = repCount;


            $.extend(this, { //it using the current instance as the return 
                get volume1() {
                    return repCount * weight;
                }
            });


        }

        $.extend(Set.prototype, {
            get volume2() {
                return this.weight;
            }
        });

        var firstSet = new Set(135, 8);

        document.write(JSON.stringify(firstSet));
        document.write("<br />");
        document.write(firstSet.volume1);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `extend` does not copy getter/setter - https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6145

Without the `get` it kind of works:

```
function Set(defaults) {
    $.extend(this, {
        repCount: undefined,
        weight: undefined,
        volume1: function() {
            return this.repCount * this.weight;
        }
    });

    if (defaults) {
        $.extend(this, defaults);
    }
}

$.extend(Set.prototype, {
    volume2: function() {
        return this.repCount * this.weight;
    }
});

var firstSet = new Set({
    weight: 135,
    repCount: 8
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(firstSet));
document.write("<br />");
document.write(firstSet.volume2());
```

Answer (score 1):

As @pkyeck mentioned, jQuery's `extend` does not copy getters/setters. You'll have to add those properties afterwards.

For `volume1` you can try this:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "volume1", {
  get: function() {
    return this.repCount * this.weight;
  }
});
```

For `volume2`:

```
var p = Set.prototype;
Object.defineProperty(p, "volume2", {
  get: function() {
    return this.repCount * this.weight;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.defineProperty(Set.prototype, "volume2", {
    get: function () {
        return this.repCount * this.weight;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Comment: That's explicitly marked as deprecated in the very question you're linking?

Comment: Sorry for that...Updated